# How to Print Dataframe in a way that similar to Excel?

Tags: python

[Excel picture]
[1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/192IP.png

I want to print row width same as headers width.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve quality of questions you ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest [`DataFrame.to_markdown`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html?highlight=to_markdown#pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

result = df2.to_markdown()
print(result)


|    |   a |   b |   c |
|---:|----:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |
|  1 |   4 |   5 |   6 |
|  2 |   7 |   8 |   9 |
```

Markdown is HTML compatible

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 | 8 | 9 |